# Apache 2.4.16 proxy no longer working

Tags: apache, proxy

I have been using Gateone behind an Apache proxy for a long time. All of a sudden, probably after the last apt-get update/upgrade of my Debian Jessie install, this no longer works.
The error I get in the error.log is this :

> [Sat Sep 12 16:20:47.992400 2015] [proxy:warn] [pid 1870] [client  192.168.0.2:5022] AH01144: No protocol handler was valid for the URL /gateone/. If you are using a DSO version of mod_proxy, make sure the proxy submodules are included in the configuration using LoadModule.

All answers I could find were pointing to a missing proxy (sub)module that needed to be loaded. This is the list of proxy modules I have loaded :

```
proxy.conf  proxy_connect.load  proxy_html.conf  proxy_http.load
proxy.load  proxy_html.load  proxy_wstunnel.load
```

And the (unchanged) section in my http conf file looks like this :

```
            ProxyPass /gateone/ ws://localhost:8888/gateone/
            ProxyPassReverse /gateone/ ws://localhost:8888/gateone/
            ProxyPass /gateone/ wss://localhost:8888/gateone/
            ProxyPassReverse /gateone/ wss://localhost:8888/gateone/
            ProxyPass /gateone/ http://localhost:8888/gateone/
            ProxyPassReverse /gateone/ http://localhost:8888/gateone/
```

This configuration used to work. Can anyone please tell me if something has changed lately in Debian Jessie, especially regarding proxying (websockets proxying) ?

Thanks,
Hans

Answer (score 2):

2.4.17 has this exact same problem but 2.4.12 was fine.

Interestingly this ALSO occurs on the 2.4.16 and 2.4.17 Windows x64 release using  VC14 or VC11 so this is entirely something internal to the proxy modules.

The only resolution appears to be downgrading to 2.4.12 because there exists no combination of proxy modules to make it work and you can use your config in 2.4.12 without issue.  Definite websocket proxy break 2.4.16+

*Update: Workaround allows http: fallback from ws: when you use ProxyPass with a very specific URL.
Eg.

```
#Works 2.4.12 but fails 2.4.16+
ProxyPass /ws/ ws://localhost:8080/ws/

#2.4.16+ seems to want full and exact path and ws: fails but http: failover works
ProxyPass /ws/stomp/ http://localhost:8080/ws/stomp/
```